# Is it too late in the year to aerate lawn, St. Louis Missouri? I know it is not going to go below freezing within a week but I don’t know after that

Tags: aeration

Is it too late in the year to aerate my lawn in St. Louis Missouri? I know it is not going to go below freezing within a week but I don’t know after that.

Comment: It would be better to ask a general question about timing of aeration.  Future visitors seeing this question is, say, April will better understand it.

Comment: There's already one somewhat like that, (when and how much) which has at least one answer that suggests that if it's possible, and it needs it, you can do it whenever. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/107/6806